# VMware Workstation - Installing Red hat Linux 5.4

Tags: vmware-workstation, redhat-enterprise-linux

I installed Red hat linux 5.4 on my VMware workstation and it worked finem but the filesize of linux was not as per my requirements.

VMware only gave 3GB to my root (`/`) which is very small. How can I adjust the filesize of linux while installing it on VMware.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare has no control over how large filesystems are; it only has control over how large a block device to grant to the guest VM. If you want to give the VM guest a larger block device, it might be easier to create a new VM from scratch. (While the `resize2fs(8)` tool can resize filesystems, it scares me.) Maybe you can just add another block device in VMWare, so that you can mount it on `/usr` or `/home` or `/var`, wherever it would make most sense for your deployment.

If you dislike how the Red Hat installer has partitioned your guest block devices, that has nothing to do with VMWare, and instead on choices made during installation. A 3gig `/` sounds fine to me, assuming you've got more storage on other filesystems.

Comment: i need to install oracle on this machine... do you still think 3GB is fine..

Comment: @ShahJee, no idea: (a) depends on the sizes of your other filesystems (b) depends on the amount of data you intend to store in your oracle deployment.

Comment: okay, let me give you a brief how i am going about this installation. As you have eloquently said that VMware has nothing to do with file size (very true). It only gives you an option of hard disk size. Now after installation when i df -h my os it only gives 3 gb to my root. I want to extend this. How can i extend this. Because when you are installing without VMware linux ask you about its file size. Here i am not given this option as VMware fixes itself...

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the VM when you create it and specify the disk size.

Comment: Disk size does not affect the file structure of OS

Comment: What do you mean disk size does not affect the file structure of OS? RHEL allocates the remaining free space on the disk to the root (after allocating /boot) unless you specifically override the default partitioning scheme.

Comment: no it does not... atleast not in my case.

Comment: Post the output of cat /proc/partitions and df so we can see your allocations.